# Resnick - Probability Path - Exercise 6.16 (c)

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Resnick's books:

> For any sequence of random variables {$X_n$} set $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$
>
> (c) Show $X_n \xrightarrow{P} 0$ does NOT imply $S_n/n \xrightarrow{P} 0$.
>
> Hint: Try $X_n = 2^n$ with probability $n^{-1}$ and $=0$ with probability  $1-n^{-1}.$

I could show the first part, that $X_n \xrightarrow{P} 0$, by taking:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n = 0) = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n}) = 1$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X_n - 0|\leq \epsilon) =1 $

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X_n - 0|> \epsilon) =0 $, by taking complements.

How can I show the second part, that $S_n/n \xrightarrow{P} 0$ does not apply?

Comment: I think there is a copy error in your statement of the problem. Shouldn't it be $S_n/n$? That's how I saw it on the text. Of course, your version is true too. The solution manual is really available online of you search for it, however I would like to see a different solution.

Comment: That's right, it is $S_n/n$. I found the solution manual, but it uses another method which was very messy for me, so I'm trying to figure out how it works with this first hint. Also, that's why I omitted the second hint, which leads to the solution found on this manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue as follows. We show that:
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|S_n|  \ge n) \ge 1 - \frac{1}{e}.$$ Indeed fix $n = 2^l$ for some integer $l$ (in the end we will take $l \to \infty$). Then 
$$
\mathbb{P}(|S_n| \ge n) \ge \mathbb{P}( \exists m \ge l, \text{ such that } X_m \neq 0) = 1 -\Big( 1 -\frac{1}{n} \Big)^{K(n)}
$$
Indeed the first inequality follows since for such $m$ we would get $S_n/n \ge X_m/n \ge 1.$ The latter equality follows on the other side by counting the probability of at least one success in a sequence of Bernoulli trials. $K(n)$ indicates the number of trials, namely the number of admissible $m$, that is:
$$K(n) = 
\#\{m: \ \ l \le m  \le  2^l \} = 2^l {-} l{+}1.$$

Hence $K(n) \simeq n.$ Passing to the limit (over $l$ or $n$) on the right hand side gives then the solution.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, it made me see another simple solution based on yours

Answer (score 1):

For any given $\epsilon>0$, arbitrarily close to $0$, we would have that:

$P(|\frac{S_n}{n}|>\epsilon)=P([X_{n_{0}}=0,X_{n_{0}+1}=0,\dots,X_n=0]^c)= 1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-n_0}$

So that $n_0$ is the minimum value such that $X_i\geq n$, to guarantee that for any $\epsilon$ is true that $\frac{S_n}{n}>\epsilon$.

Now, taking limits both sides
$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|\frac{S_n}{n}|>\epsilon)=\lim_{n\to\infty}[1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-n_0}] =1- \lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-n_0} = 1-\frac{1}{e} \neq 0$

Obs: Note that, since $n_0$ is a fixed value $\lim_{n\to\infty}[1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-n_0}] =\lim_{n\to\infty}[1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n}]=\frac{1}{e} $

So that $\frac{S_n}{n}\nrightarrow^{P}0$

Comment: Note that for $\epsilon > 0$ fixed and $n$ large at will $X_1 \neq 0$ is not  enough to ensure that $S_n/n > \epsilon.$ This is the reason why I looked at indices $m \ge \log_2(n).$ But the idea is the same. In fact my calculations show that the number of terms we do not consider is $o(n).$

Comment: Good point. But for any large enough $n$ there will always exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\frac{S_n}{n}>\epsilon$ will be true. If we choose, for example, $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ this should solve the problem. Does $\epsilon$ need to be fixed to guarantee convergence in probability, or I can make such a choice for it?

Comment: The mathematical mantra of limits goes "For ANY $\epsilon$ > 0 there exists an $n_{\epsilon}$ such that $\forall n \ge n_{\epsilon}$ ...". So no, such a choice would be wrong.

Comment: So you need to look an index big enough so that at least $\frac{S_n}{n}\geq 1$, in order to avoid this case...

Comment: Yes, but $n_0$ cannot be independent of $n$. The larger $n,$ the larger $n_0$. You are eventually converging to my proof :)